# Java: Getting a variable name from a string

Tags: java, string, variables

I have some variables defined like this.

```
public final static String pDrive = "\\\\fs-innova1\\projects\\";
public final static String hDrive = "\\\\fs-innova1\\hr-department\\";
public final static String iDrive = "\\\\fs-innova1\\innova\\";
```

Then later in my program I have a string that says "p:\blah\blah\blah"  I would like to look at the first char in that string and call the variable like Char(0)+"Drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a `Map<String, String>` instead:

```
private static final Map<String, String> DRIVE_MAPPINGS = new HashMap<>();

static {
    DRIVE_MAPPINGS.put("p", "\\\\fs-innova1\\projects\\");
    DRIVE_MAPPINGS.put("h", "\\\\fs-innova1\\hr-department\\");
    DRIVE_MAPPINGS.put("i", "\\\\fs-innova1\\innova\\");
}
```

Then use

```
String mapping = DRIVE_MAPPINGS.get(input.substring(0, 1));
```

(Alternatively, if you're really only ever going to want the key to be a single character, use a `Map<Character, String>` - it's the same idea.)

I would personally create an immutable map using [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), but again the principle is the same - that would just make it obvious that you weren't going to change the contents of the map after construction.

Comment: Nitpicking, but Java 6 EOL was Feb '13, might as well promote using the diamond notation. :)

Comment: Well, I agree about Guava, but if it's not on the classpath, Collections.unmodifiableMap() would already be a good thing.

Comment: @TC1: Done here as it lets me get it all on one line - but I think a *lot* of Java coders are still on 6 (or even 5).

Comment: @JonSkeet I know they are, I've seen 4 still in production, but of all the places, I think SO is on the top of the list to push knowledge of new features, especially since these make it more readable. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to name variables at runtime. Your best bet is to use a map.